# “Beautiful of” VS. “Beauty of”?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, nouns

I can’t understand that how do we use **of** after *adjectives* ?

> - It was beautiful of you to...
> - It was kind of you to...
> - It was generous of you to...

---

As I know, it is possible to use **of** after “nouns”.

> - It was beauty of you to...
> - It was kindness of you to...
> - It was generosity of you to...

But how can that be possible in terms of adjectives?

Comment: The syntax of *It is/was X of you to [do something]* requires that ***X*** should be an ***adjective***, not a noun. None of your second set of examples are valid.

Comment: You can use *of* after nouns, but not the way you're using them there.  The correct way to use *of* with nouns is just something like "The beauty of the trees was breathtaking."

Comment: Your beauty, your kindness and your generosity etc. And I am sure it is the same thing in your own language. Most languages have adjectives and nouns.

Comment: There is nothing to understand: this happens to be the way we say it in English. Tᴚoɯɐuo's answer gives you a summary of the grammar, but it doesn't explain _why_ we say it that way, because there is no such explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**of you** refers to "you" (him, her, them, etc) as possessing a quality or attribute.

You have behaved in a way that is characterized by an adjective and that attribute is then attributed to **you** (her, him, etc).

> It was generous **of you** to lend me your car so I could pick up my girlfriend at the airport.

The (possibly optional) complement specifies the action or behavior in the form of a non-finite clause:

> It is kind of you *to say so*.

The non-finite clause supplies the idea-content for  **it** exposed at the head of the sentence.

It (i.e. "to say so") was kind  of you.

If the thing to which **it** refers is already established in context, the non-finite clause is not needed:

> I didn't mention your prison record when introducing you to my parents.
>   -- I know. I was there. It was kind of you.
>   But we will have to let them know at some point.

With the noun, we would say **on your part** instead of **of you**.

> It was a kindness **on your part**  not to mention my juvenile prison record when introducing me to your parents.

Answer (score 1):

The second set of examples are not correct. This is how they *could* be rewritten, while still keeping the noun.

- ... was an act of kindness  ...
- You showed kindness when you ...
- You showed generosity when you ...
- Your beauty shone through when you ...

Let me know if you need a more precise answer.